# Django1.10 - /i18n/setlang/ CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: internationalization, csrf, django-1.10

After selecting a language in a language switcher form, I got a CSRF error:

The form is in **base.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post" class="form-inline">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input name="next" type="hidden" value="" />
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
      <select name="language" class="form-control" id="lang-switcher">
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
          <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
            {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
          </option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I submit the form with JS:

```
jQuery('#lang-switcher').change(
    function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
    });
```

my template file **art.html** is as follow:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
  ....
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py** is as follow:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from .models import Exhibition, Picture

def index(req):
  highlight = Exhibition.objects.latest()
  exhibitions = Exhibition.objects.all()[1:]
  return render_to_response('art.html', RequestContext(req,{'highlight': highlight, 'exhibitions': exhibitions}))
```

**urls.py** is as follow:

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^art/', index),
  url(r'^$', views.flatpage, {'url': '/home/'}, name='home')
]
```

I can load the page w/o problems, then when I submit the form to switch language I get the CSRF error.

**edit**

I must add that the form works well when I'm on root.

Comment: Clearing browser cache solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved it by using a different render function in my view:

```
  return render(req, 'art.html', {'highlight': highlight, 'exhibitions': exhibitions})
```

Comment: thank you for you solution! I had the same issue, really strange behaviour.